# Pass arguments into search results

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am creating a search function for a custom post type on my wordpress site, and I need to filter out search results based off an ACF True/False field. I have to use WP_Query to pass arguments since the generic wordpress loop does not allow that, but when I use WP_Query the query returns all the posts based on the arguments I passed, and disregards the actual search term.

```
<?php $args = array( 
  'post_type' => 'work',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'work_hidden',
      'value' => '0',
      'compare' => '=='
    )
  )
); 

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    include "partials/work-card.php";
  } 
endif; ?>
```

How can I use WP_Query to include the search term and the arguments.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

First the 'compare' when you want equals in SQL MUST be a single '=';

Next you have to put the search parameter as from the [Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter), assuming is `$_GET['search']`:

```
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'work',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's' => $_GET['search'],
    'meta_query' => array(
         array(
            'key' => 'work_hidden',
            'value' => '0',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the timely response! 

Unfortunately $_GET['search'] does not pass the search term to my argument. I actually tried passing a explicit value to the 's' key just to see if it would work and it did not. It appears 's' key is getting ignored... I wonder if it has anything to do with me using the Relevanssi search result plugin...

Comment: It could be. Try using the `$wpdb` object passing directly the SQL query.

Comment: my query parameter is 's' (e.g. website.com/?s=NYC) -- if I echo $_GET['s'] I can see my search term, but when I try to pass it as a value to 's' is my query argument no posts are displayed... Which I know isn't true because if I use the standard WP Loop I can see results for that search term.

Comment: You can try to put the search in another element of the meta query array with a relation 'AND' pointing to the field you want to search in. But you will achieve the same goal. Don't know why it is not working for you. Here is a [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78649/using-meta-query-meta-query-with-a-search-query-s) where someone achieve what you are trying to do and asks for a more tricky thing.